# Jenkins Docker plugin is showing offline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, docker, boot2docker, dockerpy

I have integrated the [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) with Jenkins.

I am sure the integration was done success as after installing I checked the "Test Connection" and it showing my Docker version correctly.

Now I have trying to provision slave from my build and it is failing. I am getting:

```
pending  #5     
(pending—All nodes of label ‘docker test’ are offline
```

Can anyone please help me how to debug this?

Comment: Version for Jenkins & ssh slave plugin ,also the Jenkins log

Comment: I also faced lots of different issues with this plugin but it's still under heavy development. You should try with the latest version (0.9.0-rc2 as of today)

Comment: Hi,
I have been facing the same issue. did you resolve it?

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this?